# Can't access PowerBi Report Server from outside of Network

Tags: powerbi, windows-server-2019

*Scenario*

I'm using **Power Bi Report Server - Developer (15.0.1107.116)** which is directly connected to **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Database** and **Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Database**, the Operating System is **Microsoft Window Server 2019** with **Internet Information Service (IIS)**. IIS already has `/RDWeb` web portal on 443 port and PBiRS is also on 443 port, both with legit SSL Certificate. Locally both `/RDWeb` and `/Report` are accessible in the local area network. I'm also able to connect to IIS main web page from outside of network.

*Issue*

I can connect with the Report Server `/Report` web portal on Local Network but when I try to connect to `/Report` from outside of the network, I get an error of 404 though the same `/Report` is accessible from Local Area Network.

*Points to Note*

- Firewall is off of (Domain/Private/Public)
- Server is in DMZ
- IIS Main Webpage is accessible from outside the network
- Only `/Report` is not accessible from outside network

Answer (score 0):

*Please keep in mind that this guide is of HTTP `8080` insecure protocol based*.

Before starting, I'm assuming that the Power Bi Report Server service running properly, the database is connected successfully and Web URLs are not yet set.

Steps

1. Go to **Web Service URL** tab and click `APPLY`.
   [image]
   *Note: Once applied, you will see a link on the same page.*
2. Similarly go to **Web Portal URL** tab and click `APPLY`.
   [image]
   *Note: Once applied, you will see a link on the same page. The virtual directory is actually sub directory for accessing Power Bi Report Server web portal.*

Things to keep in mind.

- Database should be **SQL Server 2012** or later.
- Port `80` must be allowed in Firewall for inbound traffic.
- Port `80` must be forwarded in the modem.
- You must have public Static IP from your ISP.

Now you can check for localhost as `http://localhost/virtual-directory` and hopefully it will work, then you can check with your public static ip like `http://your-public-static-ip/virtual-directory` where in this case *virtual_directory*  is `Reports` from step 2.

Examples
In case if *virtual_directory* is **Reports** from step 2.

- For Local: `http://localhost/Reports`
- For Public: `http://your-public-static-ip/Reports`